# Elasticsearch cant filter field named 'id'

Tags: search, filter, elasticsearch

For some reason it won't let me filter on nested fields with a field name of `id`

**Mapping**

```
    {
    "mappings": {
        "user": {
            "_id": {
                "path": "userID"
            },
            "properties": {
                ...,
                "languages": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "id": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "level": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "learning": {
                            "type": "boolean"
                        },
                        "teaching": {
                            "type": "boolean"
                        }
                    }
                },
                ...,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Indexed Document**

```
_source: {
    ...,
    languages: [{
        id: 11,
        level: "4",
        learning: true
    }, {
        id: 192,
        level: "5",
        learning: true
    }, {
        id: 3,
        level: "6",
        teaching: true
    }, {
        id: 165,
        level: "2",
        learning: true
    }],
    ...,
}
```

The problem arises here, if I search for the term `id` then I get nothing, no matter what value I use.

**Query**
curl -XGET localhost:9200/users/user/_search -d

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "languages",
                    "filter": {
                        "term": {
                            "id": 165
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I replace `"id": 25` with something like `"level": 5` (or anything other than id) then I get what I'm searching.

Is there some hidden trick when working with filtering fields name `id` that I'm missing?

Comment: Works for me. Tested in ES 1.4.0.

Comment: I gave up and just renamed it to `languagesID` and now it works...